# Cup product of 3-dimensional lens spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is there a simple way to compute the cup product structure of $L(p,q)=L_p(1,q)$ without generalizing to higher dimensional lens spaces? Hatcher shows two ways to compute the general cup structure: one in Section 3.3. page 251 and one that uses Bockstein homomorphisms in Section 3.E. page 304. I just need to show that $x\smile\beta(x)$ is a generator of $H^3(L,\mathbb{Z}_p)$ when $x$ is a generator of $H^1(L,\mathbb{Z}_p)$, as in this case the Bockstein homomorphism is an isomorphism.

Comment: You can see this on-page $363$ of [this book](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~ralph/math215b/Bredon.pdf). The point is cup product paring gives an isomorphism.